# Unity - How to create a game-save with a preview image?

Tags: unity, c#, savegame, json

I want my game-save to be shown with a preview image.
This is often seen in City Builder games: The game-save usually has a name, a date and often also provides a preview of the build city (just a screenshot of what was seen on the screen when the user pressed Save).

For my game, I provide 16 game-save slots, and they all get saved in "one big" JSON file.
For testing purposes, I currently take a screenshot, convert it to a Texture2D and assign it to the game-save slot in my UI.

**What would be a good way to store the preview-screenshots so that it is available the next time the game is started?**

The most obvious way would be to convert the screenshot to a png file, and save it together with the one big JSON file. But that would mean that the game-saves are no longer all just in one JSON file, but instead also rely on a separate file that holds the preview image, and that for each different game-save.
(Downside: 1. Player can see the actuall png files in the save folder 2. with 16 save games, we now don't have only one save file, but 17 (16 screenshots, 1 JSON file))

Since I would like to have the save file to consist of only one file, I was considering to not save the screenshot at all, and just take new screenshots every time the game starts (based on the information stored in the JSON file). Since I am working on a small game, with only one scene, this would be easily possible. But this does not seem like an elegant solution.
(Upside: Only one save file needs to be stored: the JSON file)

I found this [reply](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/132357/130588) to a question about complex save systems, which hints into the direction of storing a screenshot with the binary formatter. Would it be possible to save a collection of Texture2D in one file, using the binary formatter? If yes, where can I read more about that and, would it be possible to save the Texture collection together with the JSON file, to have only one save file in the end (or alternatively 2 files: 1 JSON + 1 File that holds all 16 previews)?

Comment: Could you tell us why you think the downsides you see are downsides to you? Why is it so important to have a single file, and what's so bad about the player being able to see the screenshots?

Comment: @Vaillancourt I would assume it is "saver" to not show the raw screenshots, because a random user could feel encouraged to play around with these "nice looking screenshots". This can potentially break the previews if they delete or rename these files. One single file makes it easier to make backups or send game saves to friends/other users. Having one save game consist of multiple files makes it generally speaking easier for the user to break named game save.

Comment: If they play around with the screenshots, they can play around with your json file as well.

Comment: Keep in mind that you'll still need to validate any input your savegame will provide, unless you don't mind them cheating by editing them :)

Comment: I was really mostly talking about users that do NOT know what they are doing ;)

Comment: One more drawback about the all in one fie (regardless if with screenshot or without). If it gets corrupted, say byw bye to all your 16 saved games. If you save them each in a separate file, at least the user has a fall back and only one might be gone.

Comment: @Zibelas good point!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're working with JSON format already, you could simply include the preview image as a Base64 blob that can be decoded on the fly when reading the savegame list.

Assuming you have access to a **Texture2D** representing your savegame preview (let's call it `previewImage`), you can do the following:

```
public string EncodePreview(Texture2D previewImage) {
    byte[] previewBytes = previewImage.EncodeToJPG();
    string previewBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(previewBytes);
    return previewBase64;
}
```

This way, you can save the image as a string in the same JSON file where you keep the savegame data. When it's time to show up the save slots, you can convert the image back as follows:

```
public Texture2D DecodePreview(string previewBase64) {
    byte[] previewBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(previewBase64);

    Texture2D previewImage = new Texture2D(0, 0);
    if (ImageConversion.LoadImage(previewImage, previewBytes))
        return previewImage;
    else
        return null;
}
```